# Auto Updating Text Labels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently trying to get show screen coordinates on my little thing I made.. but I am having issues refreshing the text to the new X, Y values.

```
int x = Cursor.Position.X;
int y = Cursor.Position.Y;

textBox1.Text = "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + "";
textBox1.Refresh();
```

That's what I have, but I don't understand why it isn't refreshing? If someone can explain it to me it would be great.

Comment: You mean, when you move the mouse? Do you handle the event handler for mouse move? Where is this code?

Comment: Yes, For when you move your mouse

Comment: So, do you handle the appropriate event?

Comment: wait .-. nope, I thought Cursor.Position would automatically fetch and re update every move of the mouse..

Comment: See my answer how to resolve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patrick Hofman has told you, you must handle the mouse move event. Try this code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form1_MouseMove);
}

void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = Cursor.Position.X;
    int y = Cursor.Position.Y;

    textBox1.Text = "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + "";
}
```

Comment: `Refresh` is meaningless in this context. It's enough to simply set `Text`. And subscription to `MouseMove` inside `Load` event handler is ... unusual. This looks wrong, unless you have explanation why are you doing it like this.

Comment: @Sinatr you are right. The textBox refresh is there because i just copied the OP code. Anyway, i was going to delete my answer, as Patrick Hofman's is better and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

The text doesn't magically update itself.

You have to handle the appropriate event, for example [`MouseMove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your form.

So hook up the event in the constructor;

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent(); // this is usually already there

    this.MouseMove += Form1_MouseMove;
}
```

Then call your code inside the event handler:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = Cursor.Position.X;
    int y = Cursor.Position.Y;

    textBox1.Text = "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + "";
}
```

Note that this might get slow when there are a lot of events raised. You can build some timer mechanism to update every once in a while, depending on your needs.

Comment: @Jack: any reason you unaccepted my answer? Anything wrong with it? Did you really check the code of the other guy, since that won't work.

Comment: I don't understand it either, i was going to delete my answer